# How does Front-end development affects User Experience?

Tags: frontend-development, programming

Real world examples will be the best answers :)

One of the basic examples I can think of, is when the front-end developer builds the website not in an efficient way that causes some actions to be slow.

Comment: This question is simply too broad. No one answer to this.

Comment: @DA01 I understand that, but I'm looking for examples. I think that every UX designer encountered sometime in front-end things that affected the experience with the product.

Comment: Sure, but this is a Question and Answer site. A question asked is meant to be answerable. A bunch of examples isn't a good fit. Good discussion topic, just not ideal for a Q/A site.

Comment: Maybe you can suggest where can I ask people for examples from their experience?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO,  I don't think the question has one solution and also does not approaches the intent in the right way .

This is a classic delivery mindset problem .  Isn't it mandatory for the Front end developer to actually make sure the User experience is the numero uno priority , right from **utilizing cache effectively** to making sure there is **no complex loops** in our JS .

It is understood that the strict timelines  we'd have to adhere to sometimes causes things to roll out of control,but when we step back and do a usability testing ofvarious scenarios , for eg: network throttling. we can see a number of issues.

Fortunately , UX is not only relegated to a bunch of fancy animations and ARIA color contrasts anymore.

From a developer perceptive, it would be better if we take a look at these things

- use browser cache and server cache effectivetly
- memory management in JS (using chrome audits)
- using CSS [effectively](https://nystudio107.com/blog/implementing-critical-css)  , make sure above the fold content renders instantaneously
- and dont dump big libraries for small features.

My two cents based on experience :) !

Comment: I think the OP is not asking for how to optimize the front-end. He wants to know how the non-optimized front-end affects user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the department of website development, **anything that makes the user experience of the site unpleasant directly affects on how the user reacts to your product**.

The example you put above on the front-end development is just one entity of the website development team. Imagine that the front-end developers have done a great job in optimizing the website to the best, **but the data coming from back-end is taking a lot of time**. And when both (the front-end and back-end developers) have done the perfect job, **but the user is not able to consume the content well, because the content developer has not written understandable content**. And the list goes on....

Eventually, everyone in the team have to do their jobs well to make the user experience of the site usable, delightful, understandable; so the users use your product without getting annoyed.

Comment: Totally agree with you, but I'm looking only for front-end "mistakes".

Comment: @dimshik Looking at front-end mistakes won't improve the UX of the site. You don't launch only the front-end when you launch website right?